# Не могу понять, почему scrapy не проходит по другим ссылкам

Tags: python, scrapy, web-scraping

Я написал поискового бота на Scrapy/

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Selector
from scrapy.spiders import Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

from Diplom.items import QuestionItem


class ConsultSpyder(scrapy.Spider):
      name = "consultation"
      allowed_domains = ['health.mail.ru']
      start_urls = [
       "https://health.mail.ru/consultation/1579497"  # откуда начинать
      ]

      rules = {
         Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('./consultation/\d+',)), callback='parse_item', follow=True),

          }

      def parse(self, response):  # метод обработки ответа
          root = Selector(response)
          posts = root.xpath(r'//div[@class="column column_content"]')
          for post in posts:
              item = QuestionItem()
              item['text'] = posts.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div['
                                   '2]/div[2]').extract()
              yield item
```

Хочу чтоб он проходил по всем страницам https://health.mail.ru/consultation/1579497++
Проблема состоит в том , что парсится только страница которая в start_urls, а правила как будто игнорируются. Скорее всего я не правильно задаю Rule. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема.

Comment: начните с замены имени метода на `parse_item`

Comment: Спасибо , хоть и не решило моей проблемы., но помогло избежать другую.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете базовый класс, а вам нужен CrawlSpider - https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло.